# run multiple methods from array

Tags: ruby

I need to run multiple methods from an array like the folowing example, first approach works but i'd rather let just run the methods without displaying the result. How to adapt the second approach so that i don't get the error below ?

```
def method1
  print 1
end

def method2
  print 2
end

[method1, method2].each(&p) #=>12 (works)

[method1, method2].each(&method(:run)) 
#=>12 `method': undefined method `run' for class `Object' (NameError)
```

Comment: Your methods print things. Why would you want to run them if you don't want the printing?

Comment: just run, the print inside is just to seee waht is happening

Comment: Yeah, so they are running, aren't they? Remove print and you're good, no?

Comment: you are missing teh point Sergio, i want to run the methods without using the p, thanks anyway, i got the answer allready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `method1` invokes the method (rather than referring to it), your arrays actually contain the results of running the methods, not references to the methods themselves.

You probably want:

```
[:method1, :method2].each {|m| method(m).call}
```